# Prove that for every graph, there exists a bipartite graph to which it is homeomorphic.

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that for every graph, there exists a bipartite graph to which it is homeomorphic.

I couldn't prove it, I don't even have a clue on how to start. My knowledge on graph theory is pretty basic too.

Comment: Subdivide every edge.

Comment: Could you expand on that?

Comment: Subdividing every edge makes the result bipartite and it is clearly homeomorphic to the original graph.

Comment: Hmm I kind of see it, but how can you be sure you're not creating odd cycles?

Comment: Color each of the original vertices red, color each of the new vertices blue. Show that this is a proper coloring.

Answer (score 2):

As [Leen Droogendijk](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/95972/leen-droogendijk) said in the comments, just take every edge in your given graph and subdivide it.

To convince yourself that the resulting graph is bipartite, color the original vertices red, and the new vertices blue. No two red vertices are adjacent because any edge connecting them has been subdivided with a blue vertex. All the blue vertices were constructed to be only adjacent to two red vertices.